# How to store Call Data Record in MySQL directly from freeswitch on Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, sqlite, freeswitch

I am using freeswitch on windows. I want to store all the call records in the MySQL or SQLite Database directly from freeswitch.

I can see the cdr been stored in Master.csv. But on the forum it mentions that we can store the CDR directly to database.

I can store the CDR using the CSV but I don't want to do that way.

Can anyone tell me how I can store the CDR directly to the database on windows for freeswitch ?

Thanks 
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways.

load mod_cdr_sqlite to save your CDRon SQLite.
load mod_odbc_cdr   to use odbc and connect to MySQL.

You can also create a PHP page that saves CDRs and call it from Freeswitch using mod_xml_cdr.

Start from https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CDR

Comment: Is it possible on Windows ? I am new to freeSwitch..  Do I need any dll for connecting the database.. like what we have for "mod_cdr_csv.dll"..

It will be helpful if you could explain in details.

Thanks

Comment: It seems not all modules have a windows version, sorry: I use only Linux.
mod_xml_cdr(.dll?) has a windows version.

You have to:
- load the module
- configure it declaring an url where CDR POST will be shot for any call
- create a web page that read this POST and insert it into DB (I use php)

To have an example of PHP page see

https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch-contrib/browse/trixter/xml-cdr